# Android Things 3 Cannot read from rxtx on Raspberry PI 3

Tags: android, arduino, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I have a Arduino configured to keep writing things on TX port, that is connected to my Raspberry Pi 3 with Android Things Developer preview 3 (I am sure that the RX/TX cables are configured right and voltages are OK).

I am trying a long time to read data and write data using PeripheralManagerService of Android Things libs.

There is an error when I start the app:

> 04-11 16:26:13.665 163-163/? I/peripheralman: type=1400 audit(0.0:44): avc: denied { read write } for name="ttyAMA0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1203 scontext=u:r:peripheralman:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
>
> 04-11 16:26:13.665 163-163/? I/peripheralman: type=1400 audit(0.0:45): avc: denied { open } for path="/dev/ttyAMA0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1203 scontext=u:r:peripheralman:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
>
> 04-11 16:26:13.665 163-163/? I/peripheralman: type=1400 audit(0.0:46): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="/dev/ttyAMA0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1203 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:peripheralman:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final int BUFFER_SIZE = 64;
private UartDevice rxtx;


public void configureUartFrame(UartDevice uart) throws IOException {
    // Configure the UART port
    uart.setBaudrate(9600);
}

public void writeUartData(UartDevice uart, String msg) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = msg.getBytes();
    int count = uart.write(buffer, buffer.length);
    Log.d(TAG, "Wrote " + count + " bytes to peripheral");
}

public void readUartBuffer(UartDevice uart) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int count;
    while ((count = uart.read(buffer, buffer.length)) > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Read " + count + " bytes from peripheral");
        Log.d("Message", new String(buffer));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
        try {
            writeUartData(rxtx, "teste");
            readUartBuffer(rxtx);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PeripheralManagerService manager = new PeripheralManagerService();

    manager.getUartDeviceList();
    List<String> portList = manager.getUartDeviceList();

    if (portList.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "No UART port available on this device:");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "List of RXTX available ports: - " + portList);
    }

    try{
       rxtx = manager.openUartDevice(portList.get(0));
       configureUartFrame(rxtx);
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Someone know what could it be ?

Comment: You could get much more help on SO if you would post (copy&paste) text code and related error, instead of some links that will eventually be dead in few days. Just a thought :)

Comment: Ok! I have edited. thx

Comment: Are you connecting directly to the RX/TX pins (8/10) on the RPi3 header, or is this a USB-TTL cable?

If you are using the native UART, have you configured the mode correctly per the docs? https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html#configuring_the_uart_mode

Comment: I am using direct RXTX on the right Pins, and yes I have configured following the docs. Sorry for late answer.

Comment: The most interesting thing is.. I did a test here, Sending Data from TX of RP3 to RX of RP3 (to itself).. And it worked fine. Baud rate / datasize / parity / stopbits, are all the same in both programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in your code where a `UartDeviceCallback` is registered. How are you polling the UART for new incoming data? Without a callback registered, your app would need to regularly poll the UART via `UartDevice.read()` for new incoming bytes, and I don't see that in your code either. The only place this seems to be called is once in the `onStart()` activity callback.

The callback is a much more efficient approach, so I would recommend adding that. For more details, have a look at the [UART Peripheral I/O Guide](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart.html).

Comment: I found what was happening, I was using Intel Arduino 101 that uses different configuration from Arduino Uno. Using Arduino Uno, everything worked fine. Thank you for the answer, it is much better use the callBack to poll data. But I really want to know what is this errors as I mentioned above.